# HTML email template is getting messed up in outlook windows

Tags: html-email

I am trying to create a simple email template and it's working fine on most of the platforms except the very famous outlook on windows7. 
It should look like this image

[image]

but it looks like in outlook(2003,07,13) on windows 7/10.

[image]

I have tried to read a lot of material and followed the rules. But in outlook nothing seems to be working. My table content is left aligned in outlook and images have a lot of space in between.

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
      <meta content="date=no" name="format-detection">
      <meta content="address=no" name="format-detection">
      <meta content="email=no" name="format-detection">
      <meta content="link=no" name="format-detection">
      <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
     <style>
    
    * { 
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
    }
    * { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
    
    img { 
     max-width: 100%; 
    }
    
    body {
     -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; 
     -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; 
     width: 100%!important; 
     height: 100%;
    }
    table.body-wrap { width: 100%;}
    p { 
     font-weight: normal; 
     font-size:14px; 
     line-height:1.6;
    }
    
    .container {
     display:block!important;
     max-width:600px!important;
     margin:0 auto!important;
     clear:both!important;
    }
    .content {
     padding:0px 15px;
     max-width:600px;
     margin:0 auto;
     display:block; 
    }
    
    .content table { width:100%; }
    @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
     table td img {
      width:100% !important;
      display:block !important;
      
     }
     table td, table td div {
      padding:0 0 20px 0 !important;
      display:block !important;
     }
     .deviceWidth {width:440px!important;}
     .center {text-align:center!important;}
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:479px) {
     .deviceWidth {width:280px!important; padding:0;}
     .center {text-align:center!important;}
    }
    
     </style>
     </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; width: 100%!important; height: 100%;margin: 0; min-width: 100%; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
    
    
    <!-- BODY -->
    <table class="body-wrap" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="body" align="center" style="margin:0 auto;border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; max-width: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
     <tbody>
      <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
       <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="display:block!important;max-width:600px!important;margin:0 auto!important;clear:both!important;">
     
        <center class="content" data-parsed="" style="min-width: 664px; width: 100%;">
         <table border="0" width="664" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="container float-center deviceWidth" style="Margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; text-align: left; width: 664px;">
          <tbody>
           <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; vertical-align: top;">
            <td class="contained" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color: #474747; font-family: Arial,sans serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.4; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; text-align: left;">
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="container deviceWidth" style="Margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
              <tr>
               <td>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                 <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/></p>
                </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </table>
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="container deviceWidth" style="Margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
              <tr>
               <td>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;padding-right:10px">
                 <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/></p>
                </div>
               </td>
               <td>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left:10px">
                 <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/></p>
                </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </table>
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="container deviceWidth" style="Margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
              <tr>
               <td>
                <div style="padding-right:10px">
                 <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/></p>
                </div>
               </td>
               <td>
                <div style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
                 <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/></p>
                </div>
               </td>
               <td>
                <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                 <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/></p>
                </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
          
          </table>
        </center>
              
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     
    
    </table><!-- Main table ends -->
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is working just fine. You're just sending it a bunch of mixed signals and you're unhappy with the results.

The easiest thing to do would be start over because your code is such a mess I don't know where to begin.

In this table, you have two classes in separate `class` declarations. Outlook will ignore `max-width` and `width: 100%`. If you want to set the width, add: `<table width="600">` to start the table. In some places you declare the size to be 664px, other places 600. Choose one and stick with it.

```
<table class="body-wrap" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
width="100%" class="body" align="center" style="margin:0 auto; 
border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; max-width: 100%; 
mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
```

The three images you have along the bottom are all sized 600px wide. That's not going to fit in a 600px box. Try resizing them to 180px-200px to work with the padding you added. You're not declaring the width on the `<td>` cells, so Outlook is filling up the full screen since it has nothing to reign it in.

Outlook does not understand `<div>` completely. You have to declare the width to ensure it properly renders them.

```
<td>
<div style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
    <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/></p>
</div>
```

Like I said, it's most likely easier to start over.

Good luck.